# RoR Tutorial Chapter 3 - Guard detects changes but doesn't fully execute tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, minitest, guard

I'm currently following the book and the video and in the video, Hartl runs a guardfile so that it automatically runs tests after any changes have been made. So in the videos when he presses return whilst in guard mode, it says:

```
17:35:31 - INFO - Running: test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb
```

followed by

```
Started 

   2/2 [=======] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.214142s
2 tests, 2 assumptions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
[1] guard(main)>
```

To which I assume that the tests have actually been executed.

But when I make changes to /test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb the guard runs but it runs up until the line where is says and that's it:

```
INFO - Running: test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb
```

I've run the guard in debug and this is what has occured:

```
chocoberry4@sample_app:~/workspace (static-pages) $ bundle exec guard -d
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Notiffany: gntp not available (Please add "gem 'ruby_gntp'" to your Gemfile and run your app with "bundle exec".).
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Notiffany: growl not available (Unsupported platform "linux-gnu").
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Notiffany: terminal_notifier not available (Unsupported platform "linux-gnu").
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Notiffany: libnotify not available (Please add "gem 'libnotify'" to your Gemfile and run your app with "bundle exec".).
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Command execution: which notify-send
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Notiffany: notifysend not available (libnotify-bin package is not installed).
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Notiffany: notifu not available (Unsupported platform "linux-gnu").
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Command execution: emacsclient --eval '1'
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Notiffany: emacs not available (Emacs client failed).
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Command execution: tmux -V
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Notiffany: file not available (No :path option given).
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Command execution: tmux -V
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Notiffany is using Tmux to send notifications.
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Command execution: tmux list-clients -F '#{client_tty}'
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Command execution: tmux show -t /dev/pts/1
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Command execution: tmux show -t /dev/pts/2
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Notiffany is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Command execution: hash stty
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Guard starts all plugins
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::Minitest
19:39:44 - INFO - Guard::Minitest 2.3.1 is running, with Minitest::Unit 5.7.0!
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Hook :start_end executed for Guard::Minitest
19:39:44 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/ubuntu/workspace'
19:39:44 - DEBUG - Start interactor
19:39:51 - DEBUG - Interactor was stopped or killed
19:39:51 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_modifications_begin executed for Guard::Minitest
19:39:51 - INFO - Running: test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb
19:39:51 - DEBUG - Command execution: tmux set -q status-left-bg red
```

Then I made a change to the file "test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb" here...

```
19:39:51 - DEBUG - Start interactor
19:39:58 - DEBUG - Interactor was stopped or killed
19:39:58 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_modifications_begin executed for Guard::Minitest
19:39:58 - INFO - Running: test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb
19:39:58 - DEBUG - Command execution: tmux set -q status-left-bg red

19:39:58 - DEBUG - Start interactor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2 tests, 2 assumptions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

means guard successfully ran 2 tests containing two assumptions (assertions).

The messages in the debug log are telling you of missing dependencies.  You could save yourself a big headache and use the free cloud 9 and heroku setup Hartl suggests, as it will just work 'out of the box'.

Otherwise you need to go through and add the missing gems the debug is complaining about, ruby_gntp and libnotify. You may get other errors afterwards, but that's where you need to start.  Run `bundle install` after adding them to your gemfile.

**Edit:** (since OP is using Cloud9)

There's a bug in the spring gem that leaves instances running until all your cloud9 RAM is consumed and Guard fails to complete due to being out of memory.  If this is the case your options are to kill spring instances or restart your app and try again.  But as your test suite grows with the tutorial killing PIDs or restarting will become too frequent to bother with.  The best solution is to not use guard on the limited memory free cloud9 account.  Just run `bundle exec rake test` when the tutorial suggests.

If there are still problems, check your gemfile exactly matches the one from the tutorial.

Comment: Well i'm using cloud9 and heroku like Hartl is. I followed the screencast and i'm still having these problems.

Comment: @jellybean_232, that's unusual then.  The only errors I had with cloud9 were when spring processes eat up all the memory, which could be solved by restarting the application.  500Mb of ram isn't enough to run guard on cloud9 without constant restarts, and even then you won't get too far into the book before you simply stop using guard and just manually run the tests.  That's what I did. :)

Comment: Guard seems to be a bit of a pain. I'm using windows which is why I'm using cloud9. Windows is a pain to run RoR =( Do you think Rspec is better for tests on Rails?

Comment: I tried the windows route too, but ended up starting over on CentOS 7, which is amazingly reliable for RoR development. Agreed, forget rails on windows.  I don't know much about Rspec, but you should stick with the inbuilt minitests for the book.  Stick with the exact gem versions Michael Hartl uses.  Check your gemfile exactly matches his in chapter 3.  If it doesn't, that could be part of the problem.

Comment: BTW guard is cute, but it's unnecessary.  If not using it solves your problems then that's what I'd do.  Just run `bundle exec rake test` whenever the book suggests it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to RoR so I'm sticking to the book. But it seems that I'll have to manually test. I'm using the exact gems Hartl uses. I also downloaded his code from GitHub and tried using guard and it has the same problems. It seems that I'll have to overlook this problem. Once I've finished the book, I may have to look into Rspec as I know this is more widely used.

Comment: thanks =) I'll just use your advice and use `bundle exec rake test`

Comment: I also tried killing spring like Hartl demonstrated in the book and the problem still persists. Manual testing seems to be the way for now.

Comment: You're welcome.  Yeah, there's no way to get through the tutorial using guard without buying more cloud9 memory. It looks like it's time for you to get dual-booting a linux distro and then, like me, you'll be driven mad with Guard popup messages everytime you change something. :)

Comment: Thanks =) I'm too scared to dual-boot but I am getting a Hand-me-down Mac soon so hopefully RoR should run better on that (hopefully =0).

Comment: Great news.  RoR runs sweet on Mac. :)  BTW please accept my answer; I know it's not what you wanted to hear, but it's a RAM issue on c9. :)

Comment: That is great to hear =), Sorry I always forget to accept answers =P Thanks